# Can' instantiate a prefab in a certain time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate a prefab in a certain time, but that gives me an error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class animatronicsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    clockTime clockTime;
    public GameObject enemy;


    void Start()
    {
        clockTime.FindObjectOfType<clockTime>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (clockTime.time2 == 10)
        {
            Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(3.66f, -1, 0.66f), Quaternion.Euler(0, -190, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

i also tryed to to spawn it by pressing a key, and it works. Can you help me resolve this?

("time2" is an int variable that count time)

Thank you

Comment: Is there a game object with the `clockTime` script attached in the scene?, What line of code is the error showing for, would you be able to share a screenshot of the debug console?

Answer (score 0):

`clockTime` variable is never initialized in your code. This is the reason of the error. Initialize it in in your `Awake()` (or anywhere before trying to access in the `Update()` method)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanted your Start to be like this

```
void Start()
{
    clockTime = FindObjectOfType<clockTime>();
}
```